# Calculate positive fractions in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, math, fractions

I tried to calculate 4/3 and store it into a float.

```
float answer = 4/3;
```

This only returns 1. Isn't objective-c able to calculate these kinds of fractions or do I have to do it any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If numerator and denominator are both integers, then division will be integer. Use

```
float answer = 4/(float)3
```

Answer (score 2):

`4` and `3` are integers. So that division is an integer division, which evaluates to `1`.

If you want a floating-point division, use (at least one) float literal.

```
float answer = 4f/3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment contains an integer divide, which returns zero if the number you are dividing by is greater. You probably meant to do:

```
float p1 = (4.0f / 3.0f);
```

or

```
float p1 = ((float)4 / 3);
```